# Asp.net, paypal and IPN.. how to automate payment?

Tags: asp.net, paypal

i'm trying to integrate Paypal in an asp.net app. 
It works fine, the last thing i would like to do is to automize payment notify.

In particular, how does it works IPN ? I would like to set a field to 1 when a user buy a service... How can i do with ipn ? 
I'm asking here to avoid to read all 120 pages of paypal IPN documentation... ;)

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 7):

Theres lots of examples out there on how to build a basic IPN listener. Once you build one and point your PayPal account at it, all transactions will have their details sent to this listener as a request. You will need to parse out the relevant data from this request to determine the success of the transaction and process the order.

[Similar SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683332/simple-paypal-ipn-examples)

[PayPal Code Sample](https://cms.paypal.com/ca/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code_ipn_code_samples)

[Other good sample C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/84538/Setting-up-PayPal-Instant-Payment-Notification-IPN.aspx)

Comment: Doesn't seem the links are valid now. This one worked for me: https://cms.paypal.com/ca/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code_ipn_code_samples